# Apache Jena: adding GraphNode (N3 formula) to Model (ARQInternalErrorException)

Tags: jena, n3

I'm attempting to add a Graph node to a Model (N3 formula)

The output should be roughly like the below:

```
<http://localhost:8080/patches/#cf0ba48fa8b0421c8b025c3ea6b41a4f>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms#Patch> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms#patches>
                <http://example.com/#me> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms#inserts> { http://example.com/#me http://example.com/#property http://example.com/#resource } .
```

Note that the `#inserts` property here is a "GraphNode" or N3 formula, I'm modelling a graph of the triples to write when a `Task` is complete

I tried the code below:

```
Model out = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
out.add(endState, SolidTerms.inserts, out.asRDFNode(NodeFactory.createGraphNode(inserts.getGraph())));
```

but this throws `[org.apache.jena.sparql.ARQInternalErrorException: Unknown node type:  {http://example.com/#me @http://example.com/#property http://example.com/#resource}]`

I've tried many other ways of putting the `Graph` in the model with no success, posting this one because it was my first and I think the most rational. Maybe it's a bug or Jena just doesn't support the GraphNode type in `RDFNode` ?

The `@` in the output puzzled me a bit, but I checked that it's not included in my property definition, it's maybe added in by the `createGraphNode` or the error serialization

Comment: Jena does not support N3 formula. `NodeFactory.createGraphNode` is no more than a placeholder and as per javadoc: "For experimentation.Otherwise, unsupported." The  rest of the code base does not know about them.

Comment: Could you link to the Java doc please ? The documentation I'm reading at https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/graph/NodeFactory.html just has: "Create a graph node. This is an N3-formula; it is not a named graph (see "quad")"